# crawler not inserting into database after certain amount of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a crawler which scrapes a website for information and then inserts the values into a database, it seems to insert the first 4000~ rows fine but then suddenly stops inserting values to the mysql database even though the crawler is still scraping the website

**Database table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog` (
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**PHP insert function**

```
function addToCatalog($id, $title, $value){
   $q = "INSERT INTO catalog VALUES('$id', '$title', $value)";
   return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);           
}
```

**php scrape function**

```
function scrape($pageNumber){
   $page = file_get_html('http://example.com/p='.$pageNumber);  

   if($page){
      $id = array();
      $title = array();
      $value = array();

      //id
      if($page->find('.productid')){
         foreach ($page->find('.productid') as $p) {
            $id[] = $p->innertext;
         }          
      }

      //title
      if($page->find('.title')){
         foreach($page->find('.title') as $p){
            $title[] = $p->innertext;
         }
      }

      //value
      if($page->find('.value')){
         foreach($page->find('.value') as $p){
            $value[] = $p->innertext;
         }
      }

      for($i=0; $i<sizeof($id); $i++){
          $add = $database->addToCatalog($id[$i], $title[$i], $value[$i]);
          echo $id[$i]." ".$title[$i]." ".$value[$i]."<br>";
      }
   }
}

for($i=0; $i<31300; $i++){
    scrape($i);
}
```

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call `addToCatalog`?

Comment: How do you know the crawler is still scraping the website after the items stop getting inserted?

Comment: Are you checking that return value from the insert query? Assuming a query succeeds is a bad bad way to go.

Comment: @MarcB because im printing the results as I go along

Comment: If there is no `.value` element on the page, or if its content is not a number, your query will fail. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to help you, have you seen my comment? Are you sure you always have a (numeric) `value` for each `productid` found? Your query will contain a syntax error if you don't.

Comment: I assure you there is no syntax error otherwise I would have debugged it in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the execution of the process stops after about 30 seconds, your problem is probably the `max_execution_time` setting.

Comment: no that can not be it, insertion time for every row takes less than a second

Comment: How long? 0.9 would be exceptionally long.

Comment: I don't know exactly since I haven't timed it, but it does not surpass my max_execution_time

Comment: `max_execution_time` is for the whole script (unless you're running it from the command line - are you?). So it may be exceeded, since you're scraping 31300 pages.

Comment: So what error do you get? You're not convincing me it's not the `max_execution_time`. PHP doesn't just stop running without a message, unless you're suppressing error messages.

Comment: OK I'll give it a shot, but surely if i stop and start the script from where i left off it should be inserting data

Comment: php keeps running because the function scrape keeps printing out the values

Comment: Sorry im not being clear, what im saying is when i start and stop the script it makes no difference, it does not insert more data.

Comment: yes previously when testing the addToCatalog function, but nothing was being printed out

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue not too long ago, turns out it was due to PHP running as FastCGI and a process daemon terminating the script, try counting the # of seconds it takes before the script exits, if its the same amount each time, try switching to CGI then trying again.

It could also be your web host terminating the script to protect shared resources, so if you are using a shared hosting server, it may be worth an upgrade.